# Migrating not possible for moderators on mobile browser

Tags: bug, migration, moderator-tools, mobile-web

When migrating a question as a moderator using a desktop browser, I can select a target site from the suggestions by typing into the "belongs on another site" field (moderators can migrate to any site in the network; normal users are shown a site-wise set list to select from):
[image: Moderator UI for migrating a question on desktop site]

In the mobile browser on my phone (Firefox 56.0 on Android, also tested it with Google Chrome 56.0 on Android), I am not shown any site suggestions when typing:

[image: Moderator UI for migrating a question on the mobile site]

It is therefore not possible for moderators to migrate questions on mobile.

Update: As Cai figured out, the issue seems to be that the pop-up is not being re-fit to small screen sizes, making the suggestions appear somewhere below the close dialog, in a position that is inaccessible from my device (I can not zoom out or scroll down further than shown in the screenshot). The required fix for this issue then seems to be to make the close dialog fit on mobile devices, so all the buttons and fields can be accessed.

Comment: Repro on a bunch of different browsers. If you move/zoom out you can see the list is actually underneath the close dialog.... the icons on the preset migration paths are about 5x too big too!

Comment: re your edit; pretty sure only mods get the site search for migrations and normal users just get to select from the set list

Comment: @curiousdannii You can use responsive site on mobile meanwhile :)

Comment: @Kulfy I prefer not to, it's usually worse.

Comment: @curiousdannii don't get your hopes up, the mobile-web interface is in the process of being discontinued in favour of the responsive design. I doubt they find it worthwhile to invest dev time on fixing things that are going to be discontinued anyway.

Comment: @Luuklag I know, it's quite sad. But maybe it's something a dev could spend 10 minutes fixing.